# How to set Paypal payment intent

Tags: paypal

I am working on a payment system with PHP and Paypal.

According to this:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

There are instructions for preparing a transaction for a Paypal payment.

It says 'Set the intent as sale, and the'. However, I want to capture the payments later.

Can I set the intent to 'authorize'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what you do. I think it is stated pretty obviously [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-payment)

"Payment intent; Must be set to sale for immediate payment or authorize for a delayed payment to be captured at a later time. Required."

Comment: YEs, I read that long ago. But the instructions for this type of payment specifically said use 'sale', so I thought it may be an exception. But I am used to these ambiguous instructions in PP documentations. But, I have to say, since they changed to oAuth, their documentation is much better.